# Imageview, last image always bigger

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a problem with my `ImageView`. The icons all display correct size, except the last one is always bigger in my `ListView`.

Can somebody please help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"        
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />


<TextView android:id="@+id/naam"
    android:textSize="14sp" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textColor="#FFFF00" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/waarde" 
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/naam"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If i change the ImageView as follows, it is ok but too big:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Edit: Problem solved, i needed to reduce the TextSize in the TextViews

Comment: describe more . possibility is that textView text length or imageView image size is bigger , so the last view .

Answer (score 0):

is this you list item layout?

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

in your ImageView is probably what is doing it - you likely need to fix the height somewhere otherwise fill_parent can push the height up if its not specified somewhere higher up in the view hierarchy - generally i fix the height it the list item root element

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

or whatever you item height should be.

Comment: geneally i find this happens when there is a view child that id fill_parent and a prent that is wrap content. You get irregular sizing. anyways thats my suggestion.